# Passing parameters for a constraint function

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints, sql-function

I have the following table that joins driver and truck tables in order to assign trucks to drivers. I need to constraint entries that belong to the same driver on the same day, and DO NOT include the same truck code.

```
CREATE TABLE Assignments(
    ID_CxC CHAR(3) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    truck_code char(3) NOT NULL REFERENCES Trucks(truck_code),
    driver_code char(5) NOT NULL REFERENCES Drivers(driver_code),
    [date] DATE NOT NULL
);
INSERT Assignments
VALUES(1,1,1,'06-11-2021');
INSERT Assignments
VALUES(2,2,2,'06-11-2021');
INSERT Assignments
VALUES(3,3,3,'06-11-2021');
INSERT Assignments
VALUES(4,4,4,'06-11-2021');
INSERT Assignments
VALUES(5,5,5,'06-11-2021');
INSERT Assignments
VALUES(6,6,6,'06-11-2021');
INSERT Assignments
VALUES(7,1,1,'06-11-2021');
INSERT Assignments
VALUES(8,2,2,'06-11-2021');
INSERT Assignments
VALUES(9,3,3,'06-11-2021');
INSERT Assignments
VALUES(10,4,4,'06-11-2021');
```

It was suggested to create a boolean function to pass along dateval, truckval and driverval, and returns the following.

```
Not Exists (Select id_CxC From Assignments
            Where Date = Dateval and Driver=Driverval
              And Truck<>Truckval)
```

I have tried creating a function returning a bit datatype, but I honestly lack knowledge on user created functions, how would I go about passing the parameters for the function?

Is there an easier approach to the whole situation?

Comment: . . As I pointed out in your earlier question:  **fix your data model**.  If you would explain what this is supposed to be doing, then I could make more concrete suggestions.

Comment: This is a learning excercise. The data model should not be changed. The point is to find a method so the only time a driver has more than one entry per date is if he is using the same truck code. There were other two scenarios, where the driver could only be assigned once per day, solved by Unique(driver_code,date), and another one where a driver can have more than one entry per day only if it's a different truck. Unique(driver_code,truck_code,date). This is now the third scenario.

Comment: . . That is really sad.  This is easily fixed with the right data model.  Without, you have to use contortions that should not be applied in the real world.

Comment: Out of the opportunity to learn, what would you add/change to the data model to be able to constraint the entries with the business requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You clearly have two different entities -- but they are related.  You have something like an "assignment" where a driver has a truck for one or more days.  Then you have something like a "trip" where a driver uses the truck (what you are currently calling an "assignment").

So, I would model this as:

```
CREATE TABLE assignments (
    ID_CxC CHAR(3) PRIMARY KEY,
    truck_code char(3) NOT NULL REFERENCES Trucks(truck_code),
    driver_code char(5) NOT NULL REFERENCES Drivers(driver_code),
    date DATE NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (driver_code, date)
);
```

Note that there is only one row per driver and per date.  Voila!  Only one truck.

```
CREATE TABLE trips (
    ID_trip INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    AssignmentId CHAR(3) NOT NULL REFERENCES Assignments(ID_CxC)
);
```

You can then add as many trips for a driver that you like, but for a given driver, they all have the same truck.